# toggle background color on a function - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I clicked a link it renders a view based on the "id" from a JSON. I need to apply a background color when a certain view renders. And I should toggle the Style.

> This code shows the crawl when I clicked a particular link.

```
handleCrawl = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.setState(current => ({
    showCrawl: { [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
  }));
};
```

> This is my render method where Ia am mapping the links and the additional details on JSON

```
    render() {
  return (


    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <h1 class="sidebar-heading">API</h1>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


    {this.state.apis.map(api => (
        <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" key={api.id}
          id={api.id}
          onClick={this.handleCrawl}>{api.title}</a></li>
          ))}

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">



      <div class="container-fluid">
      {this.state.apis.map(api => (
        <div
          key={api.id}
          id={api.id}>
          {this.state.showCrawl[api.id] && (

            <SwaggerUI url={api.opening_crawl}/>
          )}

        </div>
      ))}           
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it answers your question.
You can toggle the style conditionally.

```
{this.state.apis.map(api => (
    <div
      key={api.id}
      id={api.id}
      className={this.state.showCrawl[api.id]?"some-specific-style":"default-or-empty"}

    >
      {this.state.showCrawl[api.id] && (

        <SwaggerUI url={api.opening_crawl}/>
      )}

    </div>
  ))}
```

Comment: Glad.It helped :)